# Finding all files and folders starting with a specfic letter using upper and lowercase

Tags: command-line, files, directory, find

I recently took a midterm in my Linux class and this one command is bothering me because I thought I had it right.

My question is how would I go about finding all files and folders that start with either an uppercase or lowercase R?

Comment: In a particular directory? or recursively? do you just want to list them - or do something to the matching files?

Comment: This is what the instructions are: "Find all files and folders in the midterm folder that start with an R (upper and lowercase). A few steps before this, we had to make a directory structure. Here is the what I had for that..:Mkdir –p ~/midterm/linux/{desktops/{GNOME,KDE,LXDE,Xfce},distros/,players/{Andrew\ Tanenbaum,Linus\ Torvald,Richard\ Stallman}}

Comment: Please [edit] that information into your question

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to search from the root of the file system located at / then I would suggest running the find command such as this

```
find / -iname "r*"
```

The command work as followed:

- find - the search command
- / - Search root down (including all sub directories starting at root)
- -iname - Mean run a case insensitive search
- r* - The r is the letter and the * is a wild card which mean anything starting with r

You could also add an -ls at the end to get a listing of the results. If you don't add an ls you just get the path to the result.

Is this what you are after?

Comment: Close, the instructions that were given to us were find it in the midterm folder. I am not really sure, this whole Linux class is so confusing.

Comment: Okay my apologizes,  swap the / for the path to the folder you want to search. Also add the escape as mentioned by the other commenter's..

Comment: @PerlDuck is this what I needed  to do? find / -iname "r*"

Answer (score 0):

Read `man find` and `man 7 regex`, then do something like:

```
find / \( -type d -o -type f \) -iname 'r*'
```

Comment: Don't `-name` and `-iname` use shell globs? directing the OP to the `regex` manpage is likely to sow confusion